# In proof of Itô formula, why the $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}R_j(\Delta X_i)\to 0$ in $L^2$ where $R_j(x)=o(x^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-calculus

Let $dX_t=\mu(t,\mu)dt+\sigma (t,\mu)dB_t$. If $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$, then $$df(X_t)=f'(X_t)dX_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(X_t)dt.$$

The proof goes as follow. Let $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=t$ a partition of $[0,t]$ s.t. $\pi_n=\max_{i=0,...,n-1}|\Delta t_i|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $. I denote $$\Delta X_i=X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i},\ \ \Delta t_i=t_{i+1}-t_i.$$ Since $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$, $$f(X_t)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_{i+1})-f(X_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f'(X_i)\Delta X_i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R_i(\Delta X_i),$$
where $R_i(x)=o(x^2)$. Then, in the book of Oksendal (SDE edition 6) they say that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R_i\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $.

**Q1)** This is a mistake and should be $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R_i\to 0$ in $L^2$ when $n\to \infty $, no ? Because this is not true pointwise, no ?

---

So, I tried to prove $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R_j(\Delta X_i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\varepsilon _i(\Delta X_i)(\Delta X_i)^2,$$

---

Since $\varepsilon _i(x)\to 0$ when $x\to 0$, we know that there exist $\delta $ s.t. $|x|\leq \delta $ implies $|\varepsilon _i(x)|<1$ for all $i=0,...,n$.

Now, since $|\Delta X_i|<\delta $ for all $i$ is not true, I'm not so sure why $\varepsilon _i(\Delta X_i)<1$ for all $i$ and thus why $\varepsilon _i(\Delta X_i)\in L^1$.

**Q2)** Any idea to conclude ?

Comment: How is this possible ? Take for example $R_i(x)=\frac{x^3}{i+1}=o(x^2)$. Obviously $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}R_i(x)\not\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $. And $L^2$ convergence won't implies pointwise a.e. convergence (only that a subsequence will converges a.e.). @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs to be $L^2$ convergence in Oksendal.